# adb logcat for Phonegap on Chrome://inspect/device?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am wondering if it is possible if i run adb logcat with the Chrome Inspect/device with my phonegap app?

I am not sure how adb logcat works, or do i have to use a simulator?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean exactly? You want some console output inside your chrome developer tools while your device is plugged in? LogCat is just a simple "console" which provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing system debug output.

Comment: Hi, yer sorry, because i have no idea what the adb logcat does, i am just wondering if it would give any error code for the Java from phonegap plugins or the cores. Or if it simply return log like the console log in Chrome?

Comment: So you would like to now what exactly the ADB LogCat is and how it works? Than i would provide more information as an answer.

Comment: Yes please! And if i can use adb logcat without simulator with phonegap app etc.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is clear enough for you or if i should improve sth :-) hope i helped you!

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat (Systemlog) of Android is a System, which runs on Android Devices as long as your Device is turned on. Every Application and every process on your Smartphone are able to write messages inside this log.

But LogCat is mcuh more than that. It is so complex and full of features, that it would tike to much time to tell you about every feature. So i'm going to tell you some generall information.

---

### Log

**Command**

```
Log.i(“My Name is John”);
```

**Result**

```
My Name is John
```

---

### Log-Levels

There are some different LogLevels. They are separated into the following categories:

- Debug
- Error
- Info
- Warn

Normaly you decide on your own, what kind of Messages you want to see inside your LogCat by adding the needed command for that into your codebase.

---

### Max Log size

The maximum size of your log varies from device to device. For example on a galaxy note it is about 800Kb. As google says, the standard is at 64Kb. Maximum length of one line in LogCat is confined to 4Kb

---

### Is there a good way, to debug my application without Eclipse/Android Studio?

Yes, there is a great tool - called [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/). GapDebug is a Google Chrome "extension" and it integrates itself into it. When i started App developing all was very complicated, with GapDebug anything seems to work like a charme (at least the debugging :-) ).

If you choose to give GapDebug a try i would recommend you to install the cordova / phonegap console plugin which can be installed via `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console`.

When this plugin is installed, your can trigger console outputs via

```
console.log('My Name is John');
```

also warnings can be triggered with

```
console.warn('My Name is John');
```

All of these outputs will get posted inside your GapDebug console. It is a very comfortable way of debugging hybrid applications on any platform.

GapDebug will work with your real Device as also with your simulator.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it out. If i have the cordova-plugin-console installed, i combine it with the use of GapDebug?

Comment: Correct, and thats a very great and comfortable way to debug and developing apps.

Comment: Thanks so much, i will check it out then will accept your answer.

Comment: I am looking through the chrome/inspect further and the debugger. I am just wondering, would it means anyone that downloads a phonegap app be able to just plug it in and see all the html and javascript behinds it? Because i unchecked the debug mode from phonegap build, but i can still see all the html/javascript on the chrome/inspect

Comment: As far as i know, the apps are of course not debugable after release. The Debug Flag is gone than. I'm not as deep in android development as i'm in iOS where i could tell you how to set and remove that flag, sorry. But i think that rolled out android apps are not debugable.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking at where the apps sits, i guess because it would be sitting in the root folder, so i wont be able to use the debugger. Thanks for the info tho!